# Minimal $n$ for a polynomial to divide $x^n-1$

Tags: polynomials

Say I have a given polynomial $g(x)$ over the field $\mathbb Z_2 $. How can I find the minimal $n$ for which $g(x)|x^n-1$?

For example, I was told that for any $n<32768$, $g(x)=x^{15}+x^{14}+1$ does not divide $x^n-1$ (I have spotted that $2^{15}=32768$, however I don't know how to use this relation). How does one arrive at this conclusion?

Thanks.

Comment: Here is a really useful paper http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.121.3592&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: @rtybase I see the relevance, in the sense that the polynomials dealt with are of the right form, but I don't see how to apply this to my problem. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: You need layman's explanation?

Comment: Pretty much. This question came about as part of a homework assignment in a computer science course (dealing with CRC), rather than algebra. So I suppose the answer I'm looking for isn't this complicated.

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat of a partial answer.

Suppose, as in your specific example, that $g(X)$ is coprime to $X$ and irreducible.

Let $t=deg(g)$. Since $g(X)$ is irreducible, adjoining any of its roots generates the unique field of degree $2^t$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$, i.e. $\mathbb{F}_{2^t}$. Since this is also known to be the set of roots of $X^{2^t}-X$, we have $g(X)|X^{2^t}-X$. Therefore it is always true that $g(X)|X^{2^{deg(g)}-1}-1$.

On the other hand, it is well known that $gcd(X^n-1,X^m-1)=X^{gcd(m,n)}-1$. Therefore the minimal polynomial of the form $X^n-1$ that $g$ divides has $n\mid2^{deg(g)}-1$.

In general, I don't think we can do any better than this: considering the roots of $g(X)$ as elements of the cyclic group $\mathbb{F}_{2^{deg(g)}}^{\times}$, they all have the same order, seeing as they are conjugates via Frobenius, and $2$  is prime to $\#\mathbb{F}_{2^{deg(g)}}^{\times}$. Therefore, for example, knowing whether this minimal $n$ is $2^{deg(g)}-1$ is like knowing whether the roots of $g(X)$ are generators of the multiplicative group. I don't know of a general way of answering this question without checking this explicitly for the polynomial.

So, in your example, $g(X)$ divides $X^{2^{15}-1}-1$, and to check it doesn't divide any lower power you only need to check that $X^{m}-1\neq 0 (\text{ mod } g(X))$ for $m\neq 2^{15}-1$ dividing $2^{15}-1$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sadly I don't have the necessary mathematical knowledge to fully understand your explanation, and so it seems like this is out of the scope of what my lecturer had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

This feels like it might be useful to think about the splitting field of $g(x)$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

By using some Galois theory, you can show that there exists only one field of order $q=p^k$ for some prime $p$ and positive integer $k$, up to isomorphism.
Also, the non-zero elements of $\mathbb{F}_q$ form a multiplicative cyclic group. This means non-zero elements of $\mathbb{F}_q$ satisfy $X^{q-1}-1$.

This means if the splitting field of $g(X)$ is $\mathbb{F}_{q}$, then $g(x)$ divides $X^{q-1}-1$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$, as roots of $g(x)$ are in $\mathbb{F}_{q}$.

As for why $g(X)$ does not divide a lower power,I agree with Gal Porat is to check through the divisors of $2^{15}-1$. Although, just to reiterate you don't have to check $2^3-1$ or $2^5-1$ because if $g(X)$ did divide it, then the splitting field would be $\mathbb{F}_{2^5}$ and $\mathbb{F}_{2^3}$ instead of $\mathbb{F}_{2^{15}}$.